# Remove all text files with non-US-ASCII text encoding from current folder on Linux

Tags: beginner, c, file-system, linux

```
/* let's compile using: gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra --pedantic --std=c2x -D_GNU_SOURCE -Ofast -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7 */
/* Linux headers begin */
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
/* Linux headers end */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ALLOCATION_ATTEMPT_LIMIT 4
#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL -1

char * concat_file_path(const char * directory, const char * file_name)
{
    const char * separator = "/";
    char * result = NULL;
    size_t directory_length = strlen(directory);
    size_t file_name_length = strlen(file_name);
    size_t separator_length = strlen(separator);
    char count  = 0;
 
    while (((result = malloc(sizeof(char) * (directory_length + separator_length + file_name_length + 1))) == NULL) && (++count < ALLOCATION_ATTEMPT_LIMIT))
        sleep(1);

    if (result == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: memory allocation failed.");
    
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memcpy(result, directory, directory_length);
    memcpy(result + directory_length, separator, separator_length);
    memcpy(result + directory_length + separator_length, file_name, file_name_length + 1);

   return result;   
}

void close_directory(DIR * directory_pointer)
{
    if (closedir(directory_pointer) == 0)
    {
        puts("Directory was closed.");
    }
    else
        perror("Error: closing directory failed.");
}

DIR * open_directory(const char * directory_path)
{
    DIR * directory_pointer = opendir(directory_path);

    if (directory_pointer == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: directory stream is NULL.");
    
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    return directory_pointer;
}

char check_for_non_ascii(FILE * text_file_pointer)
{
    char current = fgetc (text_file_pointer);

    if (current == EOF)
        return FAIL;

    do
    {
        if (isascii(current) == 0)      
            return FAIL;
    }
    while ((current = fgetc (text_file_pointer)) != EOF);

    return SUCCESS;
}

void remove_if_non_us_ascii(char * full_path)
{
    FILE * text_file_pointer = fopen(full_path, "r");

    if (text_file_pointer == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: file opening error.");
    
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (check_for_non_ascii(text_file_pointer) == 0)
    {
        fclose(text_file_pointer);
    
    
        if (remove(full_path) == 0)
        {
            puts("File removed.");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Occured an error on removing a file on the path: %s", full_path);
        }
    }
    else
        fclose(text_file_pointer);
}

void perform_if_regular_file(DIR * directory_pointer, char * full_path)
{
    struct stat stat_buffer;

    if (lstat(full_path, &stat_buffer) == 0) 
    {       
        if ((stat_buffer.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG) 
        {
            remove_if_non_us_ascii(full_path);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Error: getting file information failed.");
    
        close_directory(directory_pointer);
    
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void main_loop(DIR * directory_pointer, const char * directory_path)
{   
    struct dirent * directory_entry_struct = NULL;
    char * full_path = NULL;

    while ((directory_entry_struct = readdir (directory_pointer)) != NULL)
    {
        full_path = concat_file_path(directory_path, directory_entry_struct->d_name);       
    
        perform_if_regular_file(directory_pointer, full_path);
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    const char * directory_path = ".";
    DIR * directory_pointer = open_directory(directory_path);   
    errno = 0;   

    main_loop(directory_pointer, directory_path);

    if (errno != 0)
    {
        perror("Error: reading directory entry failed.");
    
        close_directory(directory_pointer);
        
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am new to C. Please, give an advice on reliability of program, programming style and performance. You have to put program executable into a folder containing text files in any encoding on Linux machine. After running it you could have only US ASCII text files in the folder. I have tested this code on a 11 GiB storage.

Comment: Regarding the intended semantics: shouldn't the program keep empty files? If it's empty, then it certainly does not contain non-ASCII. So why return `FAIL` for this case? See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd have a function to check if a file is ASCII compatible (a positive check just to be sure that we don't get double negatives). Then if that's not the case I'd remove the file. Then I would have a generic function to remove a file if it isn't.

The whole stack `perform_if_regular_file` -> `remove_if_non_us_ascii` -> `check_for_non_ascii` seems strange to me. I would expect (in pseudo-code):

```
for all f in files
    if !regularfile(f) continue
    if !is_ascii(f) remove(f)
```

---

`exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` in `remove_if_non_us_ascii` and `perform_if_regular_file`

That doesn't seem to be a good idea: if an unexpected file is encountered then the operation is stopped midway, with no indication to the user which state the folder is in. Either continue or save up a list of files and then remove them, but don't exit prematurely.

Many OS vendors could also learn from this, by the way.

---

```
while (((result = malloc(sizeof(char) * (directory_length + separator_length + file_name_length + 1))) == NULL) && (++count < ALLOCATION_ATTEMPT_LIMIT))
    sleep(1);
```

No, just try once. If it isn't even possible to get a file name constructed then it is not time to try again, it is time to abort.

---

```
        puts("File removed.");
```

That's trace information. I'd use a logging implementation for that. But to be honest, this only makes sense if you actually *output the file name* as well.

---

Note that `isascii` will also return a positive value if the character is non-printable. Also note that Microsoft documentation tells us that it is Microsoft specific - although I have certainly found it in other systems.

Funny enough I then found a [newsgroup thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/isascii-isascii-iswascii?view=msvc-170) from 1990 that includes a comment from my old prof Tanenbaum.

Maybe better to define a macro yourself, do you really expect that a character value of 0x00 (NUL) or 0x7F (DEL) should be acceptable? But you might think differently about LF, CR and HT.

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> #define SUCCESS 0
> #define FAIL -1
> ```

Better to include `<stdbool.h>` and use its defined `false` and `true` (note that `true` is positive, though).

> ```
>     const char * separator = "/";
> ```

Simpler code if we use a single `char` for this.

> ```
>      sizeof(char) *
> ```

That's a pointless multiplication, since a `char` is always exactly 1 `char` in size.

I can't find a `free()` that releases the storage from `malloc()` - it looks like this code leaks all the memory it allocates.

> ```
>         perror("Error: closing directory failed.");
> ```

Don't end a `perror()` message with a full stop - it looks very odd with `:` after it.  Would be more useful if it indicated *which* directory:

```
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close ");
    perror(dir_name);
```

> ```
>         perror("Error: directory stream is NULL.");
> ```

Not a very user-oriented message.  `NULL` is a C concept, and meaningless to most users.  Prefer something like "*Couldn't open <directory name>*".

Comment: Note that the OP is compiling with `-std=c2x`, aka C23.  That version makes `stdbool.h` unnecessary, `true` and `false` are keywords (or predefined macros if the implementation so chooses).  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bool_constant

Answer (score 6):

`char current = fgetc (text_file_pointer);` discards the difference between an error (`int` `-1`) and a `char` with value `-1`.  Use `int` to hold `fgetc` return values.  As [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/EOF.3const.html) explains, **`EOF` is not a character (it can't be represented by unsigned
char).  It is instead a sentinel value outside of the valid range
for valid characters.**

If a `0xFF` byte is the first non-ASCII, your loop could return success thinking it reached EOF.  That's assuming you're compiling for x86, where `char` is signed in the usual ABIs, so `(char)-1` sign-extends to `(int)-1`.  For systems with unsigned `char` (like ARM), `(char)EOF == EOF` would zero-extend the `char` to `0x000000FF` which is not-equal to `0xFFFFFFFF` (`-1`), so you'd be stuck in an infinite loop with `fgetc` returning EOF.  (Glibc's `EOF` is `-1`; I was looking at how this compiled for x86 GNU/Linux.)

Use `int current = fgetc(fp);`  (Or better use `fread` to read more bytes at a time.)

---

#### Compiler options

`--std=c2x` is the upcoming C23 standard, [which gives you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bool_constant) `bool`, `true`, and `false` without even having to include `<stdbool.h>` to use them.  So generally use those instead of custom macros, unless you've looked at the compiler's assembly output and want to help the compiler save instructions by returning `0` vs. a non-zero value that might not be `1` (`true`).  Most parts of most programs aren't that performance-sensitive, and inlining of small functions usually makes this problem negligible if it existed at all.

> `gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra --pedantic --std=c2x -D_GNU_SOURCE -Ofast -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7`

Why first-gen `corei7`?  That's Nehalem from 2008, unlikely to be what you want to tune for.  If you have a Nehalem, use `-march=native` or `-march=nehalem` in GCC that isn't ancient.  As Intel kept the Core i3/5/7 branding for many generations of different microarchitectures, it became a less and less useful name for a compiler option.

`-march=x86-64-v2` is an SSE4.2 feature set (with generic tuning), like Nehalem and Silvermont-family before Alder Lake E-cores (Gracemont).  `-march=x86-64-v3` is basically Haswell, AVX2+FMA+BMI2.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels .  You can also use real microarch names with GCC's `-march` option, like `-march=skylake`, much more meaningful than `-march=corei7-avx` or `core-avx2`.

`-march=x86-64-v2 -mtune=intel` is also a thing you might want to try if you want to make code that will run on any "core i7" branded CPU (including the early generation before Sandybridge without AVX), and tuned for Intel CPUs in general, not specifically for the oldest.

`-march=x` implies `-mtune=x` so that's redundant when they're the same, but some people prefer to be explicit.

[`-Ofast`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-Ofast) can do some surprising stuff: apart from `-ffast-math`, it also enables [`-fallow-store-data-races`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fallow-store-data-races) which can turn `if (x) arr[i] = y;` into `arr[i] = x ? y : arr[i];` which isn't thread-safe if another thread is also storing to the array.  That's fine for this program, but just beware that it's not in general even safe in ways other than changing FP results.

---

#### `check_for_non_ascii` behaviour and naming

Your `check_for_non_ascii` returns true for non-empty ASCII-only files.  This seems backwards relative to the function name.  You actually called your constants `SUCCESS` and `FAIL` so these sort of make sense in the context of the whole program you're writing. But if you look at this function's task in isolation (which is a good idea when naming), it's just asking whether or not a file contains any non-ASCII characters.  Neither result is a "failure"; that would be an I/O error.  (Which it doesn't have any way to report; perhaps a third output state like negative for error vs. 0 (false) vs. positive (true).)

Also, this function seems to be responsible for detecting empty files as well.  So it's actually checking that a file consists of 1 or more ASCII characters.  You already `lstat` each file before even opening it, so you can check for size == 0 before even opening it and remove that responsibility.  (You're only doing this for regular files anyway, not symlinks or anything else.)  If the `d_type` member of `struct dirent` is available and not `DT_UNKNOWN`, though, you could avoid those `lstat` calls but wouldn't get size information.  And the file could get truncated between check and open, so maybe best to just operate in terms of reading until EOF.  Another TOCTOU race possibility is that a regular file is replaced by something else, like a pipe, or symlink to `/dev/zero` (which would make this program run forever).  `fstat` after opening would be another way to at least check that what we've opened is a regular file.  It couldn't avoid following a symlink to a different regular file, though.  For that, you'd need `open(2)` with `O_NOFOLLOW` (POSIX 2008) instead of C stdio `fopen`.

Anyway, naming is tricky, but you want a name that makes code calling it easy to read, like `if (!is_pure_ascii(fp)) { unlink(name); }`, or `if (empty_or_nonascii(fp)) { unlink(name); }`

#### Efficiently checking for non-ASCII

**Your `check_for_non_ascii` function is slow**, like hundreds of times slower than necessary (at least the user-space part) for ASCII files of at least a few KiB in size.  `fgetc` is much slower than `fgetc_unlocked` (concurrent use of the same `FILE*` is required to be thread-safe), but neither would give the compiler the opportunity to  do anything useful with your `-Ofast -march=corei7` options, and even just function-call overhead per character is not good, plus it will have to update things in the `FILE` struct pointed-to by your `FILE*`, and even `fgetc_unlocked` doesn't inline so the compiler can't just optimize them into registers.

To check a whole buffer for ASCII (after `fread`), we just need to check that none of them have their high bit set.  Probably the most efficient way to do that is to OR all the bytes together (which compilers can use [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) instructions for to process 16 or 32 at a time) and then check the MSB of the result.

This optimization is based on details of what we're checking for, specifically that US-ASCII is a 7-bit character set, padded to 8-bit in modern computers.  If you want to keep things more generic, you could potentially write `problem |= !isascii(buf[i]);` to have it unconditionally do a bunch of whatever kind of check.  But it probably won't auto-vectorize the locale-dependent table lookups for functions like `isalpha`.  The return value of `isalpha` for example is an `int` where the non-zero bit (if there is one) might be outside the low 8 bits, but `!` booleanizes.  If doing `ok &= isalpha(buf[i])` or something, you'd need `int ok = -1;` not `char ok`, but then you'd be assuming that all calls to `is...` have their non-zero bit (if any) in the same place, which is probably true but not guaranteed.  For example many of glibc's `is...` functions like `isupper` or `isalpha` use locale-dependent lookup tables of 16-bit groups of flags, so `isalnum` and `isdigit` are just different bits of the same word indexed by the 8-bit character.  Fun fact: `EOF` is a valid input to those functions, as well as as any `(unsigned char)c`, so the legal value-range of the `int character` input is usually `-1 .. 255`.

Current compilers [fail to auto-vectorize loops with an early-out condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118583/auto-vectorization-with-rust), which is why we want to write the source to unconditionally process some number of bytes.

If we look at the asm from glibc's `isascii` compiled with GCC or Clang, we see it's using `test    al, al` / `jns` which jumps according to the sign flag set by `test` according to the MSB of the byte.  So your `isascii` check isn't excluding control characters or even NUL `'\0'` bytes.  If you want that, do it manually.  `isprint` checks for "printable characters including space", but that might just be `0x20` (space) to `0x7E` (`'~'`), not newline.  So maybe `isprint(c) | isspace(c)` if you want to be picky about files you accept.  This probably defeats auto-vectorization, since even if the compiler could assume the C locale, it's almost certainly not going to invent `pcmpistri` instructions to check 16 bytes at once for being in one of the valid ranges.

Choice of buffer size: some degree of early-out is good since most non-text files will have a high byte fairly early.  `00` bytes are more common early in binary files like ELF executables, but we're accepting those, and the first byte of the ELF magic number at the start of the file is `7F`.  (`hexdump -C foo | less` and search for  `[0-F]` to check the leading digit for MSB set).

I/O from disk is normally going to work in at least 4K chunks.  (And reading from the kernel should be done at least 8K at a time; system call overhead is *high*, which is why the C stdio library does buffering for us.)  Just reading 8K even on the first `fread` is very reasonable on modern computers, the actual copying goes fast compared to overhead like page faults.  That's just two pages on x86, maybe fewer on some ISAs, and comfortably fits in L1d cache size so it'll be fast to loop over it.  If you were going to switch sizes after finding the first 4K was ok, 64KiB is a good size to amortize `read` system call overhead vs. data still fitting in L2 cache after the kernel basically does a `memcpy` from the pagecache inside the `read` system call.  Or `mmap` is very good for reading files this way, especially when they're hot in disk cache, but it's more complicated to use.

C stdio `fread` hopefully gets out of the way when doing large even-sized reads, but I notice you're calling POSIX `lstat` so you could be using `open`  (or `openat`), `read`, `close`, and `unlink` (or `unlinkat`) if you wanted to make other parts of the code  dependent on POSIX instead of just ISO C.

```
static
bool is_ascii_buffer(unsigned char *buf, size_t len){
    unsigned char setbits = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i<len ; i++){
        setbits |= buf[i];
    }
    // better would be OR reduce to one vector then _mm_movemask_epi8 to get all their sign bits with one step.
    // But not even clang is smart enough to realize that for either way of writing this check.
    return !(setbits & 0x80);
    //return setbits < 0x80;
}

int empty_or_nonascii(FILE * text_file_pointer)
{
    #define BUFSIZE 8192
    static unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE];    // on the stack (non-static) would also be ok for this size
    bool is_empty = true;
    size_t len;
    while( (len = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, text_file_pointer)) != 0 ) {
        is_empty = false;  // alternative to hoisting the first read out of the loop to special-case empty files.  The compiler might transform the loop on its own
        if (is_ascii_buffer(buf, len)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    // Unlike POSIX read,  stdio fread only returns short on EOF or error
    // It also doesn't distinguish EOF vs. error in its return value, also unlike read
    if (ferror(text_file_pointer)) {
        return -1;  // also non-zero if caller just checks for 0 vs. non-zero
    }

    // feof(text_file_pointer) must be true at this point
    return is_empty;
#undef BUFSIZE
}
```

Doing 8K `fread` calls but checking in chunks of 1K, 2K, or 4K would also make sense.  Compiler auto-vectorization is not wonderful, with reducing to scalar taking many shuffle steps instead of one `pmovmskb`.  And it has to check for odd sizes and inefficiently uses scalar `or` instead of a partially-overlapping vector (which would be fine because of how bitwise `or` works).  Although that would be less of a problem for round sizes in an outer loop over this.  Anyway, that cleanup should be a small part of the total time for zipping through text files of a few KiB or larger, and pretty trivial either way for small files.

I haven't tried to go all out in optimizing; this is still highly readable yet the compiler is able to come pretty close to what one might do by hand, doing most of the important stuff to make it fast in most cases. ( Although GCC still shoots itself in the foot by using the same vector register twice inside the loop, creating a latency bottleneck that will stop it from running at 2 vector loads per clock, except with the help of out-of-order exec.)  **[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoAPrnkpJfWQE8Ayo3QBhVLQCuLBhNJOAMngMmAByngBGmMQgAGwGAA6oCoT2DK4eXj4JSXYCAUGhLBFRegAcVpg2OQxCBEzEBGme3lzllSk1dQR5IeGRMQYKtfWNGS2Dnd0FRfolAJRWqO7EyOwcAPQAVADU9ARgHApbaCxxdJhb7kkmIFvAyMhbLEyBAHQPALQA6mK0W1%2BYqgIxCYf3ecUw6GMdg%2B70G6AApABmAAiyD0qj%2ByNMAHFgnJTEIAPJyABKzmwf0JVCYgz%2BT2WCCRqJImDwAHY6QR3EEmWhiKyORs1vCNABBTZbPLuDEITBMLDEQ4RYCBLZCkWi%2BF6RGBZAeLBbJHOfD8wQvRmIikarU6hh69wGo0KACeCjW4wI5qRVrFNt1%2BvORu5eDhXstGolUplcoVhycauFvu1/odgcRzjhtDwYTD2GtybtAcN6cixAYqFz%2Bdt9sd6bh9krSerRadQMCwEbmoLNbTzlszvBnarWBoQS2or8fkJzlFABUAJKE4KmOez7AAWWUs9Mfnn6/ns62kmHmFH5yEcmc5KEQi2GhPZ62ADFRfO/H8uNaxWs1lsFLRUAAd0iLYwncAg/zsWhfiYcDUHeAA3TBbBIPAAC9MEOQDCAQLYQxpZA8DwCNf1EBhQPOS4IS2bCCFw/DaDiBAQRILYwEgEM4mIQICAgZBZnhNlnBDBQ4iYFY%2BNmWYaJwxYILCfkmAAa3bUgtjEOjFmAeiIMAgR9ggpCUO4jCtgYPAVloZ0Xg1D0LI1MJUDcPCFFMAiiNMMCqCoSJTGARhIgsiBuSSYAgnQI5mOINUvLUpIMNMCD6AYAS2QAIQ1LYssiuoti41AwnoFhi2RO8kQysVsq2fhoogeLMESvCSrvYs0rwo1kta9q9AynrUoq0Uqqq/LCswYrBOcJk2LAfCFEIvAIC8%2BEAFY0uI5bkQExE2q2H8jiMEx1LgxDkKIEzMJkui8uQE5gAIMI1OQWVkBUw66KYCC5Se0DnQIc4Qyy70Py2Oq8DC6jjjE/lpLwF5MBeYs8xRMrKuywTkUy7L%2BS5MtppGoryutNkMd9MU7OQBynN%2BEM3LmjyvJ84hgoYULwpy6KNliv90IapLGH6zGspCsG2ae3KlHuwhDim%2B9tsF6rWNBhKILwZqNC64j0068rut6tKBdRoa/0wSWCGloSpqW1b1oxuXDcNYn5b2iICD%2B6K9PcWgIoiLZCRJLZ%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%2BE0EVBBBx4dG6oEXtPHYTk4iD1EshPAYh3iiCUH/LR88EGYQRlsWcsojioBOGcaKLAwYIAgkCYwCgarFQqQBVA1S%2BHlyAgweWVU8CLwgDTdyeBPLMMZk4qgalkrBIicso2Q8cbkU/HbQxQ10by1uXXX8cgGBZiUucZQhJCEAA0h7yjUpBfAud7ExnDs8%2BeD8yyHAUNk%2BoIKtjYEJE%2BcO0VSwkCdr%2BecEExAyK2OgVAmEGAGRxSGFewB3AhlwvCxFCEFAIxRdFVU5dwXkQQmIPRaksW525C884Dj5arJBozYgJAIDeN8Yg5BghUHhPSicrKTKPxJL2hypuDB3gYSFXhReohoIgW0JcCCG8XqHAnuralCMRHqtQHcr%2BmoHnVUwGUkVAIfHtP8YE6SLB9UUVDsQPR6lRlr0OBKgg8t5XRNaQYm03IRxuPwR4vMn8Sa2uTWLaKhr041RAQIWm80gHcWABASBfhoGh2dWKhqwbUFE0ickphwAaCqD%2BamrKaAGBUCMH9Q4lKK4g1TbMd4n57a/2QEsU0EE4n%2BQIA8J1cDXWVqCZGodayR3EDHSVKalK0HXKqvKl8b5F3XNxdamtKy1mzXmnxUdjACDhJRDLaSNz7anLOY/PdfgzFoxteYyx5woArrXROk207RVzoCZKoJ0l2IboRTfL81z5UXivNgG8kabVwebdsVtogXV%2BLEnRPiAhaQYaJfyYyzpHqEYNYw7YrrmBsC3cc%2B2raiPUeNlDD6rEppaj0MKPQVCrlVWI/yBQntx3IzxJOD9RieaNRNKdEggDkp3VwlNQYxBkoQDk2R2D9tjHjz8XRhqSmrqqaBBp2jrBMA6euXptjdQOPEFMMZlTyM1MaaUOxs61nBOMLQNyCCaszHywsWcEGUBhOieak8aCqBkBKwdVQPiUVpLbE03gUjZ1FOMGU4aHqdngRnSc9lkzeWLNsCKyYErbUuBSVvbbUqEm/DhL0NEM%2BIMtR6z84IYszhxyTmnHORcy5Vwbi3DuPcB4pKyr/PQTOEAasHtPSDCLtAxP1a2I1rdVVGPbuyuCVdwruPYAO1ER4Y0FMFwAthlI1Vnj0HQDZPj3m0ZPuygCQgEBsCfIPKYN9pJsDPcBmh%2B2bAWDIDiM6CAK2CBqS05l2H6X5PECy5VhAgOztg4h1DzCkWOskaRyj5TcVM72bOsTzzwDnPo9B%2BDyH0PcttThwpirOW8cedJ5T4rCA1JlcwDzgzlmWdVa2Atq5gt5XQ6SYaRNcGEIBIinqRIDUmfI4gMiec/ttgq8AfOhjMql29oAkoE0aWMvM91%2Bu5G19j3TbiOBBQEBuPIkR2RmiNJ9pK4e9x9H9zrkVESa9rK%2B2hVMyOydm4iurid217ds4XunuoaTRqdXmvw7ggYKYbXBGWZUdylrl3mWkEfTR9W%2BWKe1T47I268DzVZlOHS6bgnRe6LWb5Ws7X1e3aW4a3IScW3P0nr23Sx3fHjsh5uDHtTcpioA0a49vQPvA%2BT1UB9r7P2/skgBzra1Sf7byo7/OxPsv5dDxYMnBqqys0Z8uDmoiSW8/VU9rQZvJf0HyyLSWkDuGwNd7iXXhg1AT%2BL%2Bak3GxA3ui22U/KM6OG4qP%2BIETIU0m2NuS%2Bweh2o%2B4e1UoW/%2BeSdK8%2Bi%2Bu2WU72vEa%2B24G%2BW%2BAmn6u%2B1ye0s4hIyIhIEez0CirE8qLKHgvYLUxgEUXEv8xgk8J27KDAEUTwzoPsGwuKBKHABA2w/IZ%2BmSY8mB9AbeIMmiACeaV%2Bmy0B5aneUqyBBB1UkemAWhoG7qUm0u1y02UBsh5%2BgB0EL%2BdW9602O2z6w09uI%2BegT4oW1hSE8eC%2BZh22X6py/u%2BiS%2BzhLhQe3EggiW3GhI9wSw1EfBdKsK3heSII7SsKFSeGSAuWy0Cg3GPOQBWR6OARSaJR8swR02VAhhxh3%2BphYuwOoocueA3BkQkypgl%2B/IpKRgjm7SauGuFeB%2BcBZA7MFeVAhRxeeuNaamwcEEHoAiPiDMkQEBWUUBCSYithz%2BWRIBLWHo2y3kqC3ed44S9sESpylhaydUYiexjMLwgwScjoLWWwQgpg84T464s4DhyMzxrxm%2B2Ixx%2BhYR4R3hF%2BVAV%2BpgN%2BmhYxdhRR/hlBO%2B5RCSIRFh%2Bu%2BhqBoe6B4%2BecrseS6RgQkyH0N21IceeBZh02hhmeBeCmjeVeuupJS%2BRBn232pBr4fg/2PuaGDRTRwhzwGeMycQfRqegxgSFGOeIx%2BeZuyO9h1aL2Nmuitg%2BO3W4pTe16kp0x8piBve76FBLarGUJmxxezUjWyxNEP6YWHeKpgCapa2Py6AJoIMQp4GwSUG4mmp/eQOg%2BWUepL%2BzUWGH02hWR1JheWxleheFppgVp7w3o6AIClmN8ZxJxKBrRJAicHRmAXRdQ5agZ5uQxBR0JExpJHJVBv8TwqoEAXJkx8szGueHMIZ5uBpXGfG8%2BZh5eSpNJQxte6eFJEpkOB%2B%2BZ20MpVUpY5YgW/ZgM38VUJZvJVSWZkp86CO3ZUpYuBuEAQ5uczppU1uJxKJz6aJ7hY%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)**

---

#### If malloc fails, just give up

This source line is pretty long, although it's obvious what the goal is so as long as it works, I guess cramming it onto one line avoids distracting the reader from the important part.  But I'd make it just an `if` without the retry.

```
    while (((result = malloc(sizeof(char) * (directory_length + separator_length + file_name_length + 1))) == NULL) && (++count < ALLOCATION_ATTEMPT_LIMIT))
        sleep(1);
```

If the system is so short of memory that a small `malloc` fails, probably best to just exit (after maybe printing something about current progress, see other answers).   In practice on some OSes (e.g. Linux), allocation basically always succeeds, but the kernel might have to kill a process if it doesn't have the physical pages (+ swap) to back up the allocated virtual memory when processes later touch it.  This is called "overcommit".  Windows is apparently less aggressive about overcommit so allocation might actually fail, but the standard behaviour memory is to exit in that case, since that will free up memory which is vital for the overall system right now.

---

The rest of `concat_file_path` is well designed: after you do 3x `strlen` to get a total size, you're using `memcpy` efficiently rather than `strcat` which would redo the length-finding work multiple times including on the string we're building.  `sprintf` is slowish, but not compared to system calls so that would be an option (or `asprintf`, a GNU extension, returns a dynamically allocated string, so if you're going for compact source, it's very convenient.)

A `static char pathbuf[PATH_MAX]` is another option to avoid allocating, since you don't need multiple pathnames at once.  PATH_MAX is not huge on normal systems, e.g. 4096 on current Linux, so it's ok to allocate a buffer of that size, especially in a program that's using it continuously.  But [according to the `getcwd` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html), on some systems it may not even be a compile-time constant.  In a large program that spends a lot of its time *not* running this code, having a large static buffer sitting there with "dirty" data is not great.  But your program isn't that.  (Linux may actually allow longer paths, as long as each `/`-separated component is <= 255 bytes, but PATH_MAX exists for obsolete calls like `getwd`.)

With a static buffer, you wouldn't need to sum lengths before you start copying, so you could use `stpcpy` for simple and efficient concatenation.  But to still get length checking, see Linux's [`string_copying(7)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/string_copying.7.html) for a survey of the sorry state of C's length-limited string-copy functions.  Its proposed `stpecpy` in terms of POSIX.2008 `memccpy` with a stop-character of `0` might be the best bet.

**Or just use relative paths** since you're operating in the current directory: a filename you get from `readdir` works with `open` or `fopen` exactly like if `./` is prepended to it.

To work with directories other than `.`, I think the current **best practice is to use `openat`** ([man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)) which is like `open` but interprets paths relative to a directory specified by a `dirfd(DIR*)`.  Since you have the directory open to read entries, you have an FD you can use with `openat` and one of those entries without doing any path concatenation.  If you `strace` a program that opens files, you'll see glibc's `open()` wrapper function actually uses `openat(AT_FDCWD, ...` where you used to see `open(...` on older systems.  And as a bonus, inside the kernel the path lookup is simple and cheaper, not having to recheck `/foo/bar/` on the way to `baz.txt`, since the `dirfd` refer to the directory directly.  If you're recursing down subdirectories like `find` does, `child_fd = openat(dir_fd, name, O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY)` is what `find` uses, and you might use that in a recursive C function.

There's a corresponding `unlinkat` so you don't need to construct a path for that, either.

Related re: saving `lstat` system calls when looking for subdirectories using the `d_type` member of a `readdir` result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429803/how-to-list-first-level-directories-only-in-c / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958040/checking-if-a-dir-entry-returned-by-readdir-is-a-directory-link-or-file-dent/29094555#29094555

Comment: I can't believe I missed `char current` - especially after checking that the input to `isascii()` came from `fgetc()` and so didn't need converting via `unsigned char`!  This is a great review.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I only noticed while looking at the asm to see if `isascii()` was a table lookup in glibc like `isalpha()` and others.  (It's not).  I was looking for 8-bit operations, and saw a `cmp al, -1`, then realized that was a broken EOF check.

Answer (score 4):

## Use `nftw()` to recursively iterate over the directory

A lot of code you wrote is spent to recursively iterate over all the directory entries. That can all be avoided by using the standard POSIX function [`nftw()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3p.html). It also allows you to avoid concatenating path components by using the `FTW_CHDIR` option.